Typescript ESModules (.mts) in Angular
I'm trying to import a local typescript library (for testing purpose) in an brand new angular 18 project.
I'm using tsup to build the package.
When i use cjs format in my tsup.config.ts, then pack it i can locally import it in my angular project and use it without any issue.
but when i use esm format (which produce .d.mts, .mjs instead of .d.ts, .js) and import it in my angular project, i can't start it because "it doesn't find the library".
Do i need to build my own library in CJS in order to be sure to make it work with angular 18 ?
Note: as workaround i tried to replace the extension of .d.mts => .d.ts before packing it and it worked fined. But i'm not sure about my "solution".
EDIT:
i looked for angular library to see they use something similar to what i've used as "workaround"
".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/ngx-first-library.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/ngx-first-library.mjs",
      "default": "./fesm2022/ngx-first-library.mjs"
    }

